# Creating dir on deploy with a bootstrap

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, bootstrapping, dir

I need to create a dir when i deploy my web-application. This dir will contain the profilepics of all users.

code:

```
public class ImageBootstrapper {

    public static void initialise(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        boolean mkDir = new File(sce.getServletContext().getRealPath("webapps").replace('\\','/') + "/profilePictures").mkdir();

    }

}
```

- **result:**
  The creation of the dir ("profilePictures") failed..
  path he uses: C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.6/webapps/spring-1/webapps/profilePictures
- **What i need:**
  Creation of the dir ("profilePictures") at this path
  -> C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.6/webapps/spring-1/profilePictures
- spring-1 is the application context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
boolean mkDir = new File(
    sce.getServletContext().getRealPath("/profilePictures")).mkdir();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
"/profilePictures"
```

with

```
"/../profilePictures"
```